# Perform Aggregation/Set intersection on MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, set-intersection, nosql-aggregation

I have a query,  consider the following example as a intermediate data after performing some aggregation on a sample dataset;

fileid field contains the id of a file, and the user array containing array of users, who made some changes to the respective file

```
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 12  },
   “_user” : [ “a”,”b”,”c”,”d” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 13  },
   “_user” : [ “f”,”e”,”a”,”b” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 14  },
   “_user” : [ “g”,”h”,”m”,”n” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 15  },
   “_user” : [ “o”,”r”,”s”,”v” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 16  },
   “_user” : [ “x”,”y”,”z”,”a” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : 17  },
   “_user” : [ “g”,”r”,”s”,”n” ]
}
```

I need to find solution for this -> any two users that did some changes to atleast two of the same file. So the output-result should be

```
{
   “_id” : {  “fileid” : [12,13]  },
   “_user” : [ “a”,”b”]
}
{
   “_id” : {  "fileid” : [14,17]  },
   “_user” : [ “g”,”n” ]
}
{
   “_id” : {  "fileid” : [15,17]  },
   “_user” : [ “r”,”s” ]
}
```

Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't  repoid:[15,17], _user: ["r","s"]  also a match?   Not nickpicking; just want to make sure the sample output and description match.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, it should also be there.  {
   “_id” : {  “repoid” : [15,17]  },
   “_user” : [ “r”,”s” ]
}

Comment: Answer below, I believe.

Comment: I guess the query looks perfect, but after the first stage, I am getting this aggregation error. I guess there are too many array pairs created in the intermediate stage. Any ideas on how to overcome this error.           assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "BSONObj size: 45845276 (0x2BB8B1C) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: id: 0",
 "code" : 10334,
 "codeName" : "Location10334"
} :

Comment: Try setting { allowDiskUse: true } as arg #2 to the aggregate() call.
If that doesn't work, then you'll probably just have to create the pairs on the client side by taking the deduped list of users and running the for() loops in client code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat involved solution.   The idea is to first use the DB to get the population of possible pairs, then turn around and ask the DB to find the pairs in the `_user` field.   Beware that 1000s of users will create a pretty darn big pairing list.   We use `$addFields` just in case there's more to the input records than we see in the example, but if not, for efficiency replace with `$project` to cut down the amount of material flowing through the pipe.

```
//
// Stage 1:  Get unique set of username pairs.
//
c=db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$_user"}

// Create single deduped list of users:
,{$group: {_id:null, u: {$addToSet: "$_user"} }}

// Nice little double map here creates the pairs, effectively doing this:
//    for index in range(0, len(list)):
//      first = list[index]
//      for p2 in range(index+1, len(list)):
//        pairs.append([first,list[p2]])
// 
,{$addFields: {u: 
  {$map: {
    input: {$range:[0,{$size:"$u"}]},
    as: "z",
    in: {
        $map: {
            input: {$range:[{$add:[1,"$$z"]},{$size:"$u"}]},
            as: "z2",
            in: [
            {$arrayElemAt:["$u","$$z"]},
            {$arrayElemAt:["$u","$$z2"]}
            ]
        }
    }
    }}
}}

// Turn the array of array of pairs in to a nice single array of pairs:
,{$addFields: {u: {$reduce:{
        input: "$u",
        initialValue:[],
        in:{$concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this"]}
        }}
    }}
          ]);


// Stage 2:  Find pairs and tally up the fileids

doc = c.next(); // Get single output from Stage 1 above.                       

u = doc['u'];

c2=db.foo.aggregate([
{$addFields: {_x: {$map: {
                input: u,
                as: "z",
                in: {
                    n: "$$z",
                    q: {$setIsSubset: [ "$$z", "$_user" ]}
                }
            }
        }
    }}
,{$unwind: "$_x"}
,{$match: {"_x.q": true}}
//  Nice use of grouping by an ARRAY here:
,{$group: {_id: "$_x.n", v: {$push: "$_id.fileid"}, n: {$sum:1} }}
,{$match: {"n": {"$gt":1}}}
                     ]);

show(c2);
```